# Method not defined in service(' ") soapclient

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I have been researching this issue for a few hours and I haven't gotten anywhere.

I keep receiving an error when calling a webservice:

```
Error: method 'testSoap'('testSoap') not defined in service('' '')
```

However, I can see the method when I call the `__getFunctions()` method.

```
array (size=1)
 0 => string 'int testSoap(int $a, int $b)' (length=14)
```

My code looks like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($localwsdl, array('trace' => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));
$params = array('a' => 5, 'b'=> 5);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
$result = $client->testSoap($params)
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using soap call.

```
$client = new SoapClient($localwsdl, array('trace' => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));
$params = array('a' => 5, 'b'=> 5);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
$result = $client->__soapCall("testSoap",$params);
var_dump($result);
```

It will work.